# How can I add field on the fly in symfony2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to know if exist a way to add fields on the fly to any entity on Symfony2. I'm searching on the big internet and I didn't find anything. When I said "a way", I mean if exist a Doctrine Extension with that behavior, a bundle that implement it, design pattern, etc.

My idea is something similar to Translatable behavior of Doctrine Extensions. Supouse I have a Address entity, so I would like to add some attributes on the fly like street, number, intersections, and others but at the begining I didn't know what fields could exist.

I'm thinking something as 2 entities: Address and AddressFieldValues. Address will have specifics attributes like id, foreing keys of relationships with others classess and will be used to inject the dynamic attributes (a collections of field-values). AddressFieldValue will have the reals fields-values of Address, with the following attributes: id, address_id, field_name, field_value.

So, entity Address could be like this:

```
/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AddressRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="AddressFieldValues",
     *   mappedBy="object",
     *   cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private $field_value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->field_value = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getFieldValue()
    {
        return $this->field_value;
    }

    public function addFieldValue(AddressFieldValues $fv)
    {
        if (!$this->field_value->contains($fv)) {
            $this->field_value[] = $fv;
            $fv->setObject($this);
        }
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and AddressFieldValues entity could be like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="address_field_values",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *         "object_id", "field"
 *     })}
 * )
 */
class AddressFieldValues
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $field
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $field;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="field_value")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * @var string $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * Convenient constructor
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function __construct($field, $value)
    {
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }        

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set field
     *
     * @param string $field
     */
    public function setField($field)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get field
     *
     * @return string $field
     */
    public function getField()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }

    /**
     * Set object related
     *
     * @param string $object
     */
    public function setObject($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get related object
     *
     * @return object $object
     */
    public function getObject()
    {
        return $this->object;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string $content
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }        
}
```

So, if I have the following values on table: address_field_values

```
  id | object |      field      |    content
  1  |   1    |  street         | 1st Ave
  2  |   1    |  number         | 12345
  3  |   1    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
  4  |   2    |  street         | 1st Ave
  5  |   2    |  number         | 12347
  6  |   2    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
  7  |   3    |  street         | 1st Ave
  8  |   3    |  number         | 12349
  9  |   3    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
```

For now address table only have the following values:

```
|  id |
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
```

I could like to inject those fields-values to a Address object on the fly, to do something like this:

```
// if I need get de Address with id = 2
$addressRepository = $em->getRepository('Address');
$address = $addressRepository->find(2);
sprintf('The address is: "%s", #"%s" between "%s".', $address->getStreet(), $address->getNumber(), $address->getIntersections());
// then it should show: The address is 1st Ave, #12347 between 2sd Ave and 4th Ave.
//
// or if I need add a new Address, do something like this:
$address = new Address();
$address->setStreet('1st Ave');
$address->setNumber('12351');
$address->setIntersections('2sd Ave and 4th Ave');
$em->persist($address);
$em->flush();
```

then it save the address and address_field_values, and the tables have the following values:

```
// address
|  id |
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  | 
|  4  |  

// address_field_values
  id | object |      field      |    content
  1  |   1    |  street         | 1st Ave
  2  |   1    |  number         | 12345
  3  |   1    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
  4  |   2    |  street         | 1st Ave
  5  |   2    |  number         | 12347
  6  |   2    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
  7  |   3    |  street         | 1st Ave
  8  |   3    |  number         | 12349
  9  |   3    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
 10  |   4    |  street         | 1st Ave
 11  |   4    |  number         | 12351
 12  |   4    |  intersections  | 2sd Ave and 4th Ave
```

So, any ideas how can I do that?

Remember, I have as requirement in my bussiness logic that I didn't know what fields could have a Address at beginig so I need to inject the fields on the fly. I use Address as example but this behavior can be used for any entity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that your request is similar to a [collection in a form (Doctrine2 documentation)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

In the documentation, a collection of `Tags` entities with `name` property) is linked to a `Task` entity. In your case, the entity `AddressFieldValue` will have the `field` and `content` properties and the collection of `AddressFieldValue` entities will be added to `Address` entity.

So, by using this documentation and replacing `Task` by `Address` and `Tag` by `AddressFieldValue` it should works.